Что делать елси discord бот получает путсые сообщения от пользователя (python)
Здраствуйте, я написал discord бота, дал ему все разрешения и права, но при добавлении ответов на сообщения пользователя, бот начал получать только пустые строки вместо текста сообщения, подскажите пожалуйста, как это модно исправить?
Код бота:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# Создаем объект intents для разрешения нужных событий
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True  # Разрешаем получение сообщений

# Создаем объект бота
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


# Это событие вызывается, когда бот успешно подключается к Discord
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')


# Команда приветствия
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Привет, {ctx.author.mention}!')


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)
    # Не обрабатываем сообщения от бота
    if message.author.bot:
        return

    if message.content.lower() == 'Привет':
        print("Work")

    # Приветствие
    words = {'привет', 'хай', 'чё как', 'хеллоу', 'дарова', 'пр', 'прив', 'здрасьте'}
    for word in words:
        if word in message.content.lower():
            await message.channel.send(f'Привет, {message.author.display_name}, чем могу помочь?')
            break
    await bot.process_commands(message)


# Запускаем бота с помощью токена вашего приложения Discord
bot.run('токен')

